# Bulls & Cows project: cow checking

Tags: c++, project

I'm almost done with my Bulls and Cows project however if I enter a word or a sequence of numbers with an alphabet or number repeating, the 'cow' portion of the code messes up. As an example: consider the following

> Enter something that you want someone to guess: cool
>
> Time to guess! The code is of size 4. book
>
> COWS: 0 BULLS: 2
>
> ozzo
>
> COWS: 4 BULLS: 0

As you can see, after entering "ozzo", the cow value should be 2, not 4.
How can I fix this without having to change the entire code?

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != startg.getSize(); ++i){
    if (guess[i] == origWord[i]){
        bullCtr++;
    } else {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != startg.getSize(); ++j){
            if (origWord[i] == guess[j]){
                cowCtr++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code after applying fix:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != startg.getSize(); ++i){
    if (guess[i] == origWord[i]){
        bullCtr++;
    } else {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != startg.getSize(); ++j){
            if (origWord[i] == guess[j]){
                origWord[i] = 'X';
                cowCtr++;
            }
        }
    }
    origWord = origWordcpy;
}
```

Comment: There's an edit button on the lower left of your question.

Comment: ^thanks haha. first time using this website.

Comment: For each `O` in `origWord` ,two `O`'s are found in `guess`,hence giving `4` cows.There is a lot more to this problem.I don't think your approach is right.

Comment: Can you make this more conceptual? It's extremely unlikely that a "Bulls and Cows"-specific answer will be helpful to anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cow checking is problematic.

What I would do for the sake of ease (not exactly) is this (I'm talking about the else statement only):

```
for(unsigned int j = 0 ; j != startg.getSize() ; j++)
{
    if(origWord[i] == guess[j])
    {
         origWord[i] = 1; //Just assigning a certain value there to mark that we've already did something with it
         cowCtr++;
    }
}
```

And that should do the work.

**EDIT:**

You should obviously have a temporary string instead of `origWord` because changing it would affect the next iteration of the outer loop (getting the guess and comparing again) - I only showed you the way.

Comment: just tried that, thought it would work but if the original word then, is "cool", guessing "cool" doesn't end game. it says cows: 0 bulls: 0

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible implementation of the *Bulls & Cows* game:

```
// used constants; numbers to be guessed
const int first_num = 2;
const int second_num = 4;
const int third_num = 1;
const int forth_num = 5;

int main(){
// vector holding the values to be guessed
vector<int>gamenum(4);
gamenum[0] = first_num;
gamenum[1] = second_num; 
gamenum[2] = third_num;
gamenum[3] = forth_num;

// prompt message; input cycle till perfect guess (4 bulls)
int bulls = 0;
while (!(bulls == 4)){
    // vector holding the guesses
    vector<int>guesses;
    // vector input values
    int guess1(0), guess2(0), guess3(0), guess4(0);

    cout << "\t\tPlay the game ""Bulls and Cows\n""" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a set of four numbers, separated by whitespace space: ";
    cin >> guess1 >> guess2 >> guess3 >> guess4;
    guesses.push_back(guess1);
    guesses.push_back(guess2);
    guesses.push_back(guess3);
    guesses.push_back(guess4);

    // input confirmation; show your guess
    cout << "\nYour guess is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < guesses.size(); ++i){
        cout << guesses[i];
    }

    // bulls criterion
    for (int j = 0; j < guesses.size(); ++j){
        if (guesses[j] == gamenum[j]) ++bulls;
    }

    // cows criterion
    int cows = 0;
    for (int gue = 0; gue < guesses.size(); ++gue){
        for (int gam = 0; gam < gamenum.size(); ++gam){
            if (guesses[gue] == gamenum[gam] && gue != gam) ++cows;
        }
    }

    // print result
    if (bulls < 4){
        cout << "\nBulls: " << bulls << " and Cows: " << cows <<endl;
        cout << "\n\n\n" << endl;
        // reset bulls
        bulls = 0;
    }

    // empty guesses vector
    guesses.clear();
    // reset cows
    cows = 0;
}
// print success
cout << "\nPerfect Guess!" << endl;
cout << "Bulls: " << bulls << endl;
cout << "\n\n\n" << endl;

keep_window_open();
return 0;
}
```

Not optimal by any means, rudimentary, but working. **You can use it as benchmark.**